# pandas : filtering a really huge dataframe by regex from other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge csv(df1),nearly it has 3 million lines, and other csv (df2), which has 15k lines.
and I want to get the rows from df1 which will satisfy conditions mentioned in df2
written something but it taking very long time to finish
outcome of code:

> code will append "Reason" column to df1 with that of condition satisfied in df2
>   and 
>   it will append indexes of df1 to that condition of df2

Please help me in reducing execution time
and changing algorithm to achieve speed is also welcome
Ex:

```
def waived(row,df) :
    temp = (df.Violation < float(row["Limit"]))  & (df.Pin.str.contains(row["Pin"]))
    if temp.any() : 
        df.loc[temp,"Reason"] = row["Reason"]
        return df[temp].index.tolist()

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Violation': [0.5,1,2,3,4,5,6],'Pin':"kkk","aaa","bbb","ccc","abc","xyz","abcdef"]},index=[0, 1,2,3,4,5,6])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Limit': [5,3,2],'Pin': ["a+","bb*",".*"],"Reason":["Im","not","sure"]},index=[0, 1,2])
df2["Indexes"] = df2.apply(lambda row : waived(row,df1),axis=1)
```

Thanks,
Krism

Comment: You code doesn't seem to provide what you expect. After running it, I got `df1['Reason']='sure'` where `Pin=='aaa'`.

Comment: Hi @QuangHoang, :)  Pin=="aaa" satisfies conditions with  [5,"a+","Im" ] & [2,".*","sure"] and the recent "Reason" will be assigned to df1["Reason"]